# UITableViewCell shadow above the view on simulator but below in hierarchy

Tags: shadow, cashapelayer

Inside my custom UITableViewCell I add ShadowView and put all my content on it. When I run it, I see this shadows above the cell, but it hierarchy it's correctly laying below the cell. When I scroll to this cell, it's changing. What can be wrong?

```
class ShadowView: UIView {
        var layer0 = CAShapeLayer()
        var layer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        var layer2 = CAShapeLayer()
        
        init() {
            super.init(frame: .zero)
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: coder)
        }
    
        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            configShadow()
        }
        
        private func configShadow() {
            let shadowPath0 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 16)
            layer0.shadowPath = shadowPath0.cgPath
            layer0.shadowColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.03).cgColor
            layer0.shadowOpacity = 1
            layer0.shadowRadius = 5.32
            layer0.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 4.72)
            layer0.bounds = bounds
            layer0.position = center
            superview?.layer.insertSublayer(layer0, below: layer)
    
            let shadowPath1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 16)
            layer1.shadowPath = shadowPath1.cgPath
            layer1.shadowColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.04).cgColor
            layer1.shadowOpacity = 1
            layer1.shadowRadius = 17.87
            layer1.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 15.86)
            layer1.bounds = bounds
            layer1.position = center
            superview?.layer.insertSublayer(layer1, below: layer)
    
            let shadowPath2 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 16)
            layer2.shadowPath = shadowPath2.cgPath
            layer2.shadowColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.07).cgColor
            layer2.shadowOpacity = 1
            layer2.shadowRadius = 80
            layer2.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 71)
            layer2.bounds = bounds
            layer2.position = center
            superview?.layer.insertSublayer(layer2, below: layer)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "but it hierarchy it's correctly laying below the cell" mean? What does "When I scroll to this cell, it's changing" mean?

Comment: When I capture the view hierarchy, I see the shadow below the view. That's how it should be. But on device I see the shadow above the view, but when I make the part of this cell outside the tableView, the shadow becomes correct (I assume after prepareForReuse)

Comment: I have found a little fix.
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if cell.isKind(of: WalletBalanceTableViewCell.self) {
            tableView.bringSubviewToFront(cell)
        }
    }

Now I see shadow below the view, but after prepareForReuse(?) aboveAgain

Comment: How are you using the terms "above" and "below"? What do they mean here?

Comment: Above means that the shadow is fully overlaps my view (like another view on top). Below - the view drops the shadow correctly, beyond the borders of the view and the view stays the color I need.

Comment: You are adding shadow sublayers to the view. They are in front of the view itself. Therefore the shadows are in front of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of `insertSublayer(layer0, below: layer)` involves a wrong expectation. You can't put this sublayer behind the view's own layer! The correct way to cast a shadow only outside a view using a shape layer is to use a second view, behind the first view, which holds the shape layer. That way, the first view well and truly covers the second view area (so that it is never seen), and only the shadow can "leak out" from behind the first view.